# How come my OS crashes when I have more than 1 core on VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-xp, cpu

I have an XP 32 bit installation on VirtualBox, but whenever I want to increase the cores of the cpu to more than one core, the OS won't boot! What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

These two links might help:

[How to change XP VM on virtualbox to have two CPUs without having to reinstall XP](https://superuser.com/questions/369835/how-to-change-xp-vm-on-virtualbox-to-have-two-cpus-without-having-to-reinstall-x)

[VirtualBox - XP guest does not see multiple cores/multiple processors](https://superuser.com/questions/348741/virtualbox-xp-guest-does-not-see-multiple-cores-multiple-processors)

You can try ways provided in these two links. If they does not work, you might need to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! *At least in my case.*
**The problem was that I had "Virtual Machine Platform" feature enabled in Windows features.**
I had looked and looked but many nothing said about this, some people said to just turn off Hyper-V which I did but same problem. So I decided to disabled everything that had to do with "virtual" then it worked!
Also I downgraded to WSL1

Don't turn off Hyper-V, otherwise it may give you some problems like slowing down your VM (atleast it did for me).

1. Disable Virtual Machine Platform
2. Enable Hyper-V as this allows you to run WSL and Virtual machine together
   *And if you really want WSL also enable "Windows Subsystem for Linux"*
3. Downgrade to WSL1

[image: screenshot]